# How to find a desired initial condition?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am solving a set of differential equations, where the coefficient is determined by the solution itself. Here is a minimal example:

```
s = NDSolve[{M'[r] == a r^2, M[0] == 0}, M, r]; 
Plot[Evaluate[M[r] /. s], {r, 0, 1}]
```

where `a` is determined by requiring `M[r=1]=1`. Once the correct `a` is found, I then solve the equations normally and plot `M[r]`. In fortran I could iterate over `a` until such a requirement is met. I would like to know how to do this with Mathematica, or better still, do this more elegantly (not iterating, since it is time consuming in Mathematica).

Or if you find the above example too silly, here is the original problem:

```
s = NDSolve[{M'[r] == r^2 Exp[lnp[r]], lnp'[r] == - M[r]/r^2, M[0.01] == 0, lnp[0.01] == a}, {M, lnp}, {r, 0.01, 1}]
Plot[Evaluate[M[r] /. s], {r, 0.01, 1}]
```

where `a` is determined by requiring `M[1]=1`.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a neater way of doing this.

```
DSolve[D[M[r], r] == a r^2, M[r], r]
```

> {{M[r] -> (a r^3)/3 + C[1]}} . . . (eqn. 1)

From eqn. 1, when r = 0, `M[0] == C[1]`, therefore

```
M[r] == (a r^3)/3 + M[0]
```

Given M[0] = 0

```
M[r] == (a r^3)/3
```

Also given M[1] = 1, `a == 3`, therefore

```
M[r_] := r^3

Plot[M[r], {r, 0, 10}]
```

[image]